# How do I get past a Cliff in MMT?

Tags: mukashi-mukashi-aru-tokoro-ni

So I'm at a cliff in the 5 or 6th screen of むかしむかしあるところにとてつもなく仲の悪いツインテールの姉妹姫様がいらっしゃいましたとさ and I can't figure out a way past it.

I've provided a screenshot:

[image: Stuck at the cliff]

I've tried standing on top of the pollen from the mushrooms but that is too far away.

I've also tried standing on the other twintail's heads, but I can't jump high enough.

Comment: I see what you did there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55174/expanding-the-definition-of-future-se-sites-specifically-discussing-tagging

Comment: @en1gmatic325 or here: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/895 I even provided a link to download.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get on top of the platform up there. There are 2.5 methods to get on top.

1. The sign with the arrow is obscuring three blue twintails. Pick one up, charge up, and throw.

   For those who couldn't read the tutorials at the start of the stage, you can charge anything you pick up by holding down the button instead of just pressing it when throwing. This will produce special effects to occur on releasing the button. The tutorials specifically point out that Blue Twintails will make you soar upwards, while Red Twintails will make you fly forwards.
2. Picking up the spores released by a mushroom will make you float. By standing on top of the mushroom, when it releases the spores you will be sent high into the air. Pick up the spore you're standing on and simply float over. The red mushroom nearest to the cliff is the easiest.

   The 2.5 is that you can also use a spore from the giant green mushroom you might've seen earlier. This lets you skip most of the ground level, and if you get one that drifted far enough right then you can make it over the cliff. However, this wastes an excellent chain opportunity with the giant green mushroom.

Comment: I didn't know you could float on spores or about charging. This game is awesome